# Почему скрипт не читает данные из переменных взятых из get параметров url?

Tags: php, mysql

Столкнулся со странной ситуацией, выполняю sql запрос

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $coin WHERE DATE(p_date) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'");
```

иногда отдает ошибку `Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE DATE(p_date) BETWEEN '2016-07-03' AND ''' at line 1 in`, если выполнить запрос так

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ETH WHERE DATE(p_date) BETWEEN '2016-07-03' AND '2016-07-05'");
```

то запрос срабатывает.

```
$coin = $_GET['coin'];
$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];
```

Get переменные `$coin`, `$start` и `$end` 100% не пустые, через `print` выводятся без проблем.

В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно нужно убрать кавычки между переменными

Comment: `AND '''` и "100% не пустые"  явно не совпадает

Comment: при mysqli  и 100% параметрах  запрос пишется так: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples